# Regular expression splunk query

Tags: regex, splunk-query

I have a line containing

```
[India,sn_GB] Welcome : { Name:{Customer1},Place:{Mumbai},}
```

I want to print the entire line after `sn_GB]` in splunk, which is

```
Welcome : { Name:{Customer1},Place:{Mumbai},}
```

I used the below regular expression:

```
(?<=sn_).*?$
```

But it prints, along with `GB]` like `GB] Welcome : { Name:{Customer1},Place:{Mumbai},}`.
In the word `sn_GB`, `sn_` is constant and the rest two letter will vary, like `GB`, `LB`, `KB`, `TB` as such.

Please help me in correcting the regular expression.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I missed out, in the word, sn_GB , sn_ is constant and the rest two letter will vary , like GB, LB, KB, TB as such . How should I include sn_(wildcard)] in the regex ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give the correct result in case sn_GB is constant.

```
(?<=sn_GB).*?$
```

If GB is not constant you can go for:

```
(?<=sn_...).*?$
```

Comment: Hi Ashu, 
But your answer is printing along with ] . I don't require ] in the print. how to eliminate it. Any suggestions.

Comment: Add one more dot to it. 

(?<=sn_...).*?$

Comment: Yeah that worked :)

Comment: I have one more question . How to print only Place:{Mumbai} from Welcome : { Name:{Customer1},Place:{Mumbai},}

Comment: \{(.*?)\} this will give you all the values between { }

Comment: Thanks Ashu :) It works!

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question now.
Country codes are always 2 letters.
i'd use

`(?<=sn_..\]\ ).*$`

but you could use
`(?<=sn_[A-Z]{0,5}\]\ \s*).*?$`

`(?<=sn_....).*$`

is the simplest, as it will just grab 4 characters after, if it's always 2 letters for country code, and then a closing bracket and a space

Comment: Thanks Robert. That really works